# Use join to link 2 tables, creating a 3rd table with all data, then sync back changes to 3rd table to the first two

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, join

The title basically says it, but it's convoluted.  Here's what I have.  I need to create a form for a WP page that's editable to signed in users, NOT through the admin interface.  What I found is a rather nifty plugin called wpDataTables, that works very well.  Unfortunately, when you use a JOIN, it renders the form un-editable in the frontend.  That pretty well kills it for my needs.  This gives me a sad.  :(

The data I need is in two tables.  My idea is to create a third table that merges all of the data from the first two (users and pods_user) into a third, which I'll then use in wpDataTables.  Since the third one will be editable, I need to make sure changes to that are synched back to the first two tables, near real-time if possible.

Does any of this make sense, and is this something that's even possible to do with WP, phpMyAdmin, or standard SQL commands?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is not the best idea, to save redundant data in a database,  so join the tables like shown here https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109404/how-to-join-tables

Comment: The problem is that the plugin I'm using can edit data from the frontend, but ONLY if it's in one table.  Using a JOIN won't work, as their system can't update 2 tables.  Apparently the SQL to do the UPDATE is automatically generated by a script that just can't figure that all out.  So I'm sorta stuck.

Comment: make the table in mysql phpmyadmin, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html for the syntax

Comment: Thank you.  I know how to create a table.  The problem is I need 2 tables to merge into one, and keep all three in sync with their prospective data.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a third table write a view

like
to reead more about it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html  and what we would use here is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-check-option.html

It vital to read those links because views have some limitations

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT);
CREATE TABLE t2 (b INT);
CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.b WHERE a < 10
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1),(2);
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1),(2)
```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

> ```
> Records: 2  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT * FROM v1
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IYxa7dGJ)